# Expect Script - Password enterend is worng then again go to grab password

Tags: expect

i'll grab the password in first section,script will move on to section login section.There,system will check password if password entered is wrong i want to display PASSWORD INCORRECT and then again come back to grab password section.

How can i do it?

```
#Grabbing Password to be used in script further
stty -echo
send_user -- "Enter the Password: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
send_user "\n"
stty echo
set pass $expect_out(1,string)

#Loggin into the Gateway as Normal user
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No $USER@$IP
expect "$USER@$IP's password:"
send "$pass\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where using procs helps code reuse. You'll want something like:

```
proc passwd {} {
    stty -echo
    send_user -- "Enter the Password: "
    expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
    send_user "\n"
    stty echo
    return $expect_out(1,string)
}

set pass [passwd]
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No $USER@$IP
expect {
    "$USER@$IP's password:" {
        send "$pass\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    "please try again." {
        # you may need to adjust the "incorrect password" pattern there
        set pass [passwd]
        exp_continue
    }
    eof {
        send_user "you have not entered the correct password. login failed.\n"
        exit 1
    }
    -re $prompt
}

# now you're logged in
```

Comment: I am getting below error

`can't read "prompt": no such variable
    while executing
"expect {
    "$USER@$IP 's password: " {
        send "$pass\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    "please try again." {
        # you may need to adj..."
`

Comment: That's meant for you to create, it should be a regular expression that matches your shell prompt.

Comment: How to create it?

Comment: If your shell prompt ends with a dollar sign and a space, use `set prompt {\$ $}`. If it's different, then you need to specify what pattern matches your prompt. My question for you: what are you planning to do with your expect code after you send the password.

Comment: I am trying to take password as input from user and and use it in the script further.But,If the passwrod entered is wrong then script must promt that password entered is worng (consider it as password entered wrong when login into the system)